# Shorthand for matching identifier with Visual Studio regex

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Since VS2013, VS uses then .NET regex syntax, which is more standard and that is a good thing.

However, I haven't been able to find a shorthand for matching identifiers, which previously was `:i`!

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx) says that `:i` was replaced by `\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b` ... so does [this short reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

Is there really no shorter version?

Comment: No idea, but I suppose it's about consistency, a better regex engine, and compatibility with PCRE

Comment: In most simple searches `\w+` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check:

[VS2005-2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.90).aspx):

> **C/C++ Identifier**
>   `:i`
>   Shorthand for the expression (`[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*`). Matches any possible C/C++ identifier.

[VS2012-2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Match an identifier**
>   `\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b`
>   Matches `type1` but not `&type1` or `#define`.

Now, test the [new regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(_%5Cw%2B%7C%5B%5Cw-%5B0-9_%5D%5D%5Cw*)%5Cb&i=match1%20%26type1%20%23define) and [old regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Ba-zA-Z_%24%5D%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%24%5D*&i=match1%20%26type1%20%23define). The results are the same and both match `&type1` and `#define`. No idea if it is intended.

However, when it comes for shortening, `[\w-[0-9_]]` is almost equal to `\p{L}` in .NET (`\w` without 0-9 and an underscore, but still matching some Hindi and some other digits). I guess `\p{L}` was actually meant, and you can use [`\b(_\w+|\p{L}\w*)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(_%5Cw%2B%7C%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cw*)%5Cb&i=match1%20%26type1%20%23define).

If you do not want to match `&type` or `#define`, you need a [look-behind version](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3C!%5B%26%23%5D)(_%5Cw%2B%7C%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cw*)%5Cb&i=match1%20%26type1%20%23define):

```
\b(?<![&#])(_\w+|\p{L}\w*)\b
```

Or - perhaps - with [a whitespace check before the word](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%7C%5Cs)(_%5Cw%2B%7C%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cw*)%5Cb&i=%26type1%20match1%20%26type1%20%23define):

```
(?<=^|\s)(_\w+|\p{L}\w*)\b
```