# doesn't vs2012+ support regular expression shortcuts like :b, :i in Find & Replace?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

In vs2010 Find & Replace with regular expressions, `:i` can be used to match an identifier. However in vs2012+ it doesn't work. Instead you must use `\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b`. The same for `:b`, `:n` etc.

These shortcuts are really helpful to me. Just want to know are they really not supported any more in vs2012+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Visual Studio 2012 and newer versions do not support those older S&R patterns. This [*Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio* MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx) explains it:

> Visual Studio 2012 uses .NET Framework regular expressions to find and replace text. In Visual Studio 2010 and earlier versions, Visual Studio **used custom regular expression syntax** in the Find and Replace windows. **This topic explains how to convert some of the more commonly-used custom regular expression symbols to the .NET versions**.

As for identifier `:i` matching, please check my previous answer for [*Shorthand for matching identifier with Visual Studio regex*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617283/3832970) question.

Comment: Usually as the owner of the question I consider my accepting an answer as a confirmation of the helpfulness and just leave the additional upvoting to other people who found this answer useful, but I don't mind upvoting it since you asked. :)